# SharedPreferences not Reading

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I am getting weird problem with my app.
I have set-up one SharedPreference, like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        flag = prefs.getBoolean("handle_calls", false);
        if (flag) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.putBoolean("checkFlag", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

it was working fine some days before, but now this code is working fine but when I try to read these preferences in my SmsReceiver Class `SharedPreferences` doesnt read these values and default values are read (false)...Sometimes it work and most of the time it doesnt work at all! 
Here is how I am reading the `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    //flag = prefs.getBoolean("handle_calls", false);
    checkFlag = prefs.getBoolean("checkFlag", false);
    checkDecisionFlag = prefs.getBoolean("checkDecisionFlag", false);
```

This `checkDecisionFlag` is working fine but checkFlag is taking default values.

Really pissed! Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! 
This code was fine, instead the problem was with the life-cycle oriented. I had one another `SharedPreference` on which this depend. That was getting false again and again.

Answer (score 2):

remove the    editor.clear(); from if condition. as clear will clear all the data from SharedPreference.

```
 if (flag) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("checkFlag", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: also since the was working fine recently, Just once uninstall and install the app again.

Comment: Tried uninstall, and prior to writing this code, I was using code without `clear()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use if (!flag) (*not* flag) on the third line of the first code sample.